# Rewrite TypeScript property to be optional via type merging

Tags: typescript

Is there a single way to make property of type optional via intersection for example?

I was thinking that if we have type T:

```ts
type T = {
 x: string
 y: string
 z: string
}
```

then:

```ts
T & { z?: string }
```

would rewrite `z` property of `T` to become optional. But this is not the case.

How can I achieve, so `z` will be optional property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys):

> Constructs a type by picking all properties from Type and then removing Keys (string literal or union of string literals).

You'd use that to construct a new type with all properties of `T` except for `z`, and then use an intersection type to "add it back" as an optional property, like this:

```
type TWithOptionalZ = Omit<T, 'z'> & { z?: string };
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoK6oA8BcUDOwATgJYB2A5mhiLgSRVegF61FmUC+KKoksA6sWAALAPJhgxAPakAhgBsAWgiiiAtkIA8MADRQARE30A+KADJkUJgH5W9clA4BubvIjAowXDEEjxkmQVlRFQMLFx9fR1GKBoDKJRnFCA)

If you want a generic way to do this for any keys in `T`, you could do something like this:

```
type MakeOptional<T, Keys extends keyof T> = Omit<T, Keys> & Partial<Pick<T, Keys>>;

type TWithOptionalZ = MakeOptional<T, 'z'>;
```

Comment: Same here   More generic `type MakeOptional<T, Keys extends keyof T> = Omit<T, Keys> & { [K in Keys]?: T[K] }`

Comment: Or: `Omit<T, Keys> & Partial<Pick<T, Keys>>`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the good suggestions, I've tried to update my answer to incorporate them. Feel free to edit to improve clarity as needed

Comment: @Donut thanks, original answer is elegant enough and works :), so I will stick to it.